# Getting the vertices position of the polygon outline of a text in Windows

Tags: windows

Is there a way to get the position of each vertex of the outline of a text using any Windows font?

I need an algorithm where I send the text and the font and I get the vertices coordinates of each character in the text.

Comment: Which language are you using? With C# you could try to use `Graphics.MeasureString` with every char, but I don't imagine a way to calculate "blank" pixels left between chars...

Comment: @Marco, any language is welcome. What I'm interested in is in the Windows API function or .NET Framework method that reads the font information. MeasureString returns the area the text will occupy in the screen. What I need is the vertices coordinates of each character in the text I introduce

Comment: You can use GDI paths for this. Call `BeginPath` + `TextOut` + `EndPath` to create a path from a text outline. Then use `GetPath` to read the path coordinates. You can optionally call `FlattenPath` to convert curves to straight lines.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the answer in http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/f50d43fe-8206-40e5-98da-6c60630b5f73 is what you need, but give it a look.
I post part of the code that could solve your problem:

```
public struct GLYPHMETRICS
{
    public uint gmBlackBoxX;
    public uint gmBlackBoxY;
    public Point gmptGlyphOrigin;
    public short gmCellIncX;
    public short gmCellIncY;
}
public struct FIXED
{
    public ushort fract;
    public short value;
}
public struct MAT2
{
    public FIXED eM11;
    public FIXED eM12;
    public FIXED eM21;
    public FIXED eM22;
}

[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
static extern uint GetGlyphOutline(IntPtr hdc, uint uChar, uint uFormat,
   out GLYPHMETRICS lpgm, uint cbBuffer, IntPtr lpvBuffer, ref MAT2 lpmat2);




public static bool GetGlyphShape(Font font, Char c, out GLYPHMETRICS metrics)
{
    metrics = new GLYPHMETRICS();
    MAT2 matrix = new MAT2();
    matrix.eM11.value = 1;
    matrix.eM12.value = 0;
    matrix.eM21.value = 0;
    matrix.eM22.value = 1;

    using (Bitmap b = new Bitmap(1, 1))
    {
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b))
        {
            IntPtr hdc = g.GetHdc();
            IntPtr prev = SelectObject(hdc, font.ToHfont());
            int bufferSize = (int)GetGlyphOutline(
                hdc, (uint)c, (uint)2, out metrics, 0, 
                IntPtr.Zero, ref matrix);
            IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bufferSize);
            bool retval = false;
            try
            {
                retval = GetGlyphOutline(hdc, (uint)c, (uint)2, 
                         out metrics, (uint)bufferSize, 
                         buffer, ref matrix) > 0;

                g.ReleaseHdc(hdc);
            }
            catch { retval = false; }
            finally
            {
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
            }
            return retval;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use any 3d modeling software for this. For example, blender has a good support for creating text objects and exporting the obj format file, which can be opened in simple notepad. Here you can retrieve all the vertices of your required character.

Comment: But on the other hand there would be a lot of vertices. So it will take a lot of time to load all the fonts.